# How to correctly set expression Query.CommandText in SSRS?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, reportbuilder

In my SSRS report builder I have an expression set for one of my dataset (name is dsTagAttributes).  The query type is text.

This is the query expression

```
="select m.TagName, ta.descriptor, t.[State]  from MasterTags m inner join TagAttributesClassic ta on m.ID = ta.TagID inner join TagStates t on t.ID = m.StateID where m.PIServerID = @ServerID and t.[State] = @State and m.MetaData1 = @Station " & Parameters!AndOr.Value & "m.MetaData2 = @Device"
```

[image]

The above query expression has a parameter which is concatenated in the select statement.

The parameter `@AndOr` data type is text, has a default value of "or", and parameter visibility is set to hidden (screen shot below). I have set this parameter because it will be used to dynamically change the dataset result from `or` to `and` during the report runtime.

[image]

But when I run the report, an exception is thrown saying,
[image]

What could go wrong in my query command text?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run Profiler against Data Source to see the query.

I assume the problem is that you miss "'" before and after each varchar value (`@State`, `@Station`).

I wouldn't use that way to use OrAnd condition

You can modify TSQL like

```
...
    AND 
    (m.MetaData2 = @Device AND @OrAnd = 'AND')
) 
    OR
    (m.MetaData2 = @Device AND @OrAnd = 'OR')
```

Just make sure you place `')'` and `'('` correctly, depending on business logic.

Comment: you are right.  I have missed to wrap `@State`, `@Station` and `@Device` parameters with single quotes.  I thought ssrs query builder will automatically handle it since the parameters are of type text.  And, thanks for your suggestion.  What is the benefit of using your approach versus the OrAnd condition?

Comment: That's just my coding style. I noticed often a query plan was better and it could be stored in query cache without the need to compile it, and for me such approach has better readability. However that's not big issue, so you can use your approach if it's performing well.