# MS Visual Studio (Reporting Services)

Tags: visual-studio, ssrs-2008, bids

I've worked in SSRS for years but have never learned what this type of coding is actually named (which makes searching for solutions difficult), can anyone help please? Below is an example which allows the developer to have the code run as one continuous string. It also, if you're not familiar, allows for many powerful functions to be used that would otherwise (to my knowledge) not be available (e.g., IIF's, INSTR(JOIN()), SWITCH's, etc.).

```
=
 " select distinct bn " & 
 " into #ST " & 
 " from frm_cr_2021 a " & 
 " join Md..nui_crssw b " & 
 " ON a.rc=b.cy"&MID(YEAR(Parameters!frm_dt.Value),3,2)&"_rc" &
 " join nd_bs..dg_cv c " & 
 " on b.nd=c.nd " & 
 " where a.f_Dt<=@frm_dt and a.tr_dt>=@frmy_dt " & 
"(select distinct c.ln,a.RC,A.Tr_Lv,a.P_Typ,a.P_Gp,a.Eff_Date,a.Term_Date from frm_"&YEAR(Parameters!frm_dt.Value)&" a "
```

Comment: Note, the code above does not look like it did in the preview of my post... hopefully you'll be able to decipher what it is I'm tying to get information on. Each line of code starts with " and ends w/ " &

Comment: I'm not sure what the official name for it is, I always use the term "Query Expression"

Comment: If you do a Google search on SSRS Query Expressions there are no examples that are returned with that type of coding (i.e., " and " &, the beginning and end of each line of code). Is anyone aware of what that is called and how to search for examples?

Thanks for the response Alan S.

Comment: My search returned a few examples including https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44401827/how-to-correctly-set-expression-query-commandtext-in-ssrs

Comment: Great! Thank you! I'd still be interested in learning more about this if there's anyone that could provide additional information.